# New date() returning next date instead of today's date

Tags: javascript

i am trying to convert a string into date type.i am giving the string value to new date().
but it's returning next day date instead of date which i am trying to convert.

```
var endDate = new Date("2017-03-23T23:59:59.000Z");
```

//end date value is now ------ Fri Mar 24 2017 05:29:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).

Please suggest me how can get correct  date in the format MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hack can help you,

```
var endDate = new Date("2017-03-23T23:59:59.000Z").toISOString();
```

it will give you,

> "2017-03-23T23:59:59.000Z"

Further if you want to convert it to DD/MM/YYYY then you can use native javascript or lib like moment for that,
This simpile js will help to convert it to any format.

```
 var endDate = new Date("2017-03-23T23:59:59.000Z").toISOString();
 var d1 = endDate.split('T'); //spliting date from T
 var d2 = d1[0].split('-'); //getting date part 
 console.log('yyyy/MM/dd', d2[0] + "/" + d2[1] + "/" + d2[2]) //YYYY/MM/DD
 console.log("DD/MM/YYYY", d2[2] + "/" + d2[1] + "/" + d2[0])
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/9mezm5ou/)

Comment: But how can i  convert that date into MM/DD/YYYY format?

Comment: Hello, i have updated answer above, hope it work for you,press up if worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check dates, you will see that your dates differs in 5h 30 mins, that is same as your date saying `GMT +0530`. Your original date has `.000Z` that is time zone of `GMT +0`.

Make sure you use same time zone when working with date.

Try using [`Date.UTC('your date')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: How to convert date to that particular time zone ?

Comment: @Arunkumar Check update. Simply convert your date to `UTC` first

Answer (score 0):

if your time is in IST use below

```
var endDate = new Date("2017-03-23T23:59:59.00+0530");
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript `Date` objects carry no timezone information. The only reason you saw a non-UTC date is that the browser chooses by default to display dates as local time in the console. If you don't care about the date object aligning with the exact instant in local time, you can use the following `format` function to turn it into `MM/DD/YYYY` format:

```js
function format (date) {
   var mm = ('0' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
   var dd = ('0' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)
   var yyyy = date.getUTCFullYear()
   return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy
}

var endDate = new Date("2017-03-23T23:59:59.000Z")

console.log(endDate.toISOString())

console.log(format(endDate))
```

([Credit to Ranj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42572979/7256039) for posting an answer using `Date#toISOString` before mine.)

Answer (score 0):

I have created the solution over here please find below link

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD0YSGRMB59W